# I can't display image on UIButton in xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

Here is my code. I want to display three random food items image in three buttons. I check syntax, which seems ok as well. I am not sure about images. I do have 1x, 2x and 3x images in imageset.

```
import UIKit
import GameplayKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!


    var foodItems = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Add food items into Array

        foodItems.append("Apple")
        foodItems.append("Banana")
        foodItems.append("Bhindi")
        foodItems.append("Bread")
        foodItems.append("CornFlakes")
        foodItems.append("Dal Dhokli")
        foodItems.append("Egg")
        foodItems.append("Milk")
        foodItems.append("Nan")
        foodItems.append("Roti")

        // Add border to button(default color is black)

        button1.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button2.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button3.layer.borderWidth = 1

        // change border color to gray


        button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        button3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        askQuestion()
    }
    // ask question to identify foodItem

    func askQuestion() {
        foodItems = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: foodItems) as! [String]
        //set image to button 1, 2 and 3

        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: foodItems[0]), for: .normal)
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: foodItems[1]), for: .normal)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: foodItems[2]), for: .normal)

    }
```

This is simulator view. I can only see blue square. I do have 1x, 2x and 3x images in imageset.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your `Assets.xcassets`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change button type to custom in your storyboard or nib

[image]

Answer (score 2):

go to Image Asset -> Select image -> Attribute Inspector -> Render As (in Image Set) should be Default

[image: please see attachment]

Answer (score 1):

In xode 9 drag and drop is not working. You have to add file with following screen shots.
[image]

[image]

And then use your same code.

Or add image in Assets.xcassets